# Is it possible to insert an entire VB.NET DataTable into a SQL Server at once

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql, datatable

I have a SQLClient.DataSet in VB.NET, and I want to insert the entire thing into a SQL Server table without having to do the following:

```
For Each dr as Datarow in MyDataset
  Dim sc As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO MyNewTable " & _
                            "VALUES (@column1, @column2)", MyDBConnection)
  sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column1", dr.Item(0))
  sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column2", dr.Item(1))
  sc.ExecuteNonQuery()
Next
```

Since I've got close to a million rows (all pretty skinny, so it's not much space), I obviously don't want to run this loop and generate a million INSERT statements.

I know that one option is to use a linked server when I initially fetch the data, since it's coming from another SQL Server, and just have it to the INSERT from there. However, if I already have the data in my application, is there a more efficient way to bulk insert it? Can I somehow pass the DataTable as a parameter to SQL Server and have it sort it out and insert the rows?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try with [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I wanted. I had no idea this class even existed - thanks!

Comment: It inserted all one million records in about four seconds - that's perfect. Thanks again!

Answer (score 8):

With SQL Server 2008 you can use [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx):

```
Dim sc As New SqlCommand(
  "INSERT INTO MyNewTable (field1, field2,...)"&
    "SELECT field1, field2,... FROM @MyTable;", MyDBConnection) 
sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyTable", MyDataset)  
sc.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: I happen to be using 2008, and that's an awesome idea! I wonder how the performance compares to SQLBulkCopy - I'm doing it over a gigabit LAN right now, but over a slower WAN connection, any idea of the comparison?

Comment: The performance will be driven by the transfer speed (client to server) and the differenc ein the amount of data between bulk copy and TVP is minimal, so they should behave similarly. Better measure.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx)'s InsertCommand to define your Insert query.  Then call the DataAdapter's Update Method with your dataset as a parameter to have it push the data.

Something like:

```
Dim DA As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter
Dim Parm As New SqlParameter

DA.InsertCommand = New SqlCommand("Insert Into tbl1(fld0, fld1, fld2) Values(@fld0, @fld1, @fld2)", conn)
Parm = DA.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter ("@fld0", NVarChar, 50, "fld0"))
Parm = sqlDA.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter ("@fld1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "fld1"))
Parm = sqlDA.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter ("@fld2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "fld2"))
DA.Update(dataset1, "tbl1")
```

Comment: I considered this idea, but I think it still generates an INSERT statement for every row. At least it does it in the background, though, so it's cleaner for sure.

Comment: I realize this is an old post but this MSDN article appears pertinent with regard to performance... If the source and destination tables are in the same SQL Server instance, it is easier and faster to use a Transact-SQL INSERT … SELECT statement to copy the data.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could call `.WriteXML()` on the DataSet and dump that into the database in one insert.

Answer (score 0):

A way simplier way is to use a table adapter. Then you can use the Fill method to give a datatable as argument :

```
    Dim oStronglyTypedTable As StronglyTypedDataTable = GetTable() 'A custom function that creates your table from wherever you want)
    If Not oStronglyTypedTable Is Nothing Then
        Using oAdapter As New StronglyTypedTableAdapter
            Dim res As Integer = oAdapter.Update(oStronglyTypedTable)
            MsgBox(res & " rows have been updated.")
        End Using
    End If
```

Do not forget to change your Database "Copy to Output Directory" property to "Do net copy" and set your connection string properly...