# Multiple rows for insert command - Apostrophe problem

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-injection, bulkinsert, apostrophe

I'm trying to insert multiple rows using SqlCommand from C# to SQL Server. I'm forming a simple query as below:

`Insert into temp(field1, field2) values (1, 'test'), (2, 'test1'), (3, 'test2')` and so on till 100 rows. For the example purpose I only gave couple of fields here but it actually contains 25 fields and 20 out of this are strings.

this data is coming from third party API as a list and I'm forming multiple rows insert query out of that data.

I know that there is a problem of sql injection or apostrophe problem. This can be avoided by using SqlParameter. But how can I insert multiple rows without facing sql injection or apostrophe problem? Is this possible using SqlParameter?

I dont want to make multiple insert statements and send it to db, as that will slow down my process. Is there any alternative solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go with [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) Class.For more than 100 records this will be a better option.

please see this: [Is it possible to insert an entire VB.NET DataTable into a SQL Server at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533139/is-it-possible-to-insert-an-entire-vb-net-datatable-into-a-sql-server-at-once/1533157#1533157)